# Windows Server 2016 slow and interrupted file transfer

Tags: windows-server-2016, network-share

A default installation of Windows 2016:

- No domain.
- RRAS Service on 2 network adapters (default configuration).
- DHCP on local adapter.
- Local Adapter as private network (PowerShell cmdlet).
- Internet Adapter as public network.
- Default firewall configuration.
- VirtualBox with bridging network and the same OS (default installation) as IIS WebServer.
- All Windows Event Logs clean, no warnings, no errors.

Network shares on host OS, accessed from local network computers or guest OS gets file transfers on the Kb/s range, long delays or interruptions.

File transfers host <-> guest using network shares are a shame too, but work as intended using VirtualBox Shared Folders option from VBox Extensions.

Network shares on guest OS work flawlessly on the 10Mb/s to 100Mb/s range.

This is the second clean installation on different hardware (first time using HyperV for the Guest OS WebServer) that shows this behavior.

No reliable answers on Microsoft Social TechNet and tried each and every "registry hack" suggested on "SpiceWorks [SOLVED!!!] questions" but nothing worked.

Finally restored the backup to the "just installed" version to remove all weird tweaks but the issue is still alive (and boring).

I didn't made a backup before installing RRAS and this is the only difference I can see between the VirtualBox OS (works flawlessly) and the Host OS (deceivingly slow or interrupted transfers).

**EDIT**

Finally speed transfers to any device on the local network is as expected. Only one issue remains: File transfer from server to VPN computer **initiated from the client** get clogged. Anything else (VPN Client <-> Local computers) is as expected.

Comment: File transfer on VPN connections have the same issue.

Comment: Went one step forward. All local connections are working flawlessly now. We have only one issue: VPN computers can't transfer files from server. It's weird because transfers between VPN computers and local computers other than the server are fast as expected. The issue is only against the server.

Comment: Finally we've managed to get it running. Trial and error has been the tool as, even it's an issue on certain scenarios, there are no definitive answers. If anyone is interested I'll post our guidelines but, as they are very specific, I'll don't write them as an answer.